# zoom cannot start video please select another video camera

Tags: zoom-meeting, network-camera

I've just purchased a logitech C525 webcam to use with zoom conferencing.    It's installed ok on windows 10, but when I try to start video with the Logitech it says "Failed to start the video camera, please select another camera"    or something like that.       Could somebody please advise what setting I need to change to fix this?     Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Does it work in general and you get the problem only with zoom, or doesn't work at all?

Comment: It works fine locally (I'm using it with the latest version of LogitechCamera.exe).

Comment: What was the resolution of the problem? We have a camera that works fine in settings but gets the "failed to start" message while in the meeting.

Comment: I'm afraid I never got a resolution.   My wife now uses the camera exclusively on windows, and I have a different one, an HD Pro Webcam C920, which just works seamlessly, plug and play, no software required.   Sorry I couldn't be more use.